# AngularJS Exposing Multiple Services Through a Single Injectable

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for information having done a number of searches but am only able to find answers/posts relating to namespace collisions between services or methods for injecting one service into another.

Suppose I have two separate services:

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('OneService', function() {
        this.func = function() {
            console.log('service one');
        };
    })
    .service('TwoService', function() {
        this.func = function() {
            console.log('service two');
        };
    });
```

And I inject them into a factory "namespace":

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('namespace', function(OneService, TwoService) {
        return {
            OneService: OneService,
            TwoService: TwoService
        };
    });
```

I can then effectively inject both services and use them as expected with only a single dependency:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('ctrl', function(namespace) {
        namespace.OneService.func(); //=> 'service one'
        namespace.TwoService.func(); //=> 'service two'
    });
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UgF3ouyfLyUXgFWTDQdf?p=preview).

This example only combines two services but could be a useful way of providing multiple "utility" functions without having to inject each one individually.

Are there any drawbacks (such as efficiency, performance) to injecting dependencies in this way, other than the potential to expose functionality to a component/scope which is then not used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are similar in this case. The difference in performance is the call of `namespace` factory function.

It's impractical to do this for single injection. `namespace` service means that there's an additional unit to test.

For multiple injections it's prone to become an antipattern. If *all* of the dependents use *all* `namespace` dependencies, this is likely should be managed through inheritance; all controllers/services can inherit from  parent class. If *some* of the dependents use *some* `namespace` dependencies, it's no better than global variable and suffers same design issues.

AngularJS DI container provides several benefits, particularly:

- testability
- lazy instantiation
- decoupling

It's also easy to comprehend how a unit works when the list of its dependencies is known.

All of those benefits are affected by single `namespace` dependency.